# How do I add an object to the node tree at a specific position

Tags: godot

I'm making a skiing game, and a part of that is programmatically adding snow to the scene in a specific place. It will all be the child of a single node.

I was looking through the Flappy Bird code but when it instances a scene, it only uses the function `add_child()`. There doesn't seem to be a way to set its position.

[Here is the project on github.](https://github.com/crabcrabcam/Skiing-Game)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first I would create a scene called "flag_scene". In that scene, have your code for making the flags do what you want. Every time the script I posted below is ran (and if it's put in main scene), it creates a copy of the flag scene, sets it in whatever position you want, and does the actions you assigned it to do in the script (attached to flag_scene.tscn)

```
onready var flag_scene = load("location of flag.tscn")

var timer_raw = 0
var timer

func _procces(delta):
    timer_raw += delta
    timer = round(timer_raw)

    if timer > 4:
        spawn_flag() #call every 4 seconds
        timer_raw = 0

func spawn_flag():
    flag = flag_scene.instance()
    flag.set_pos([where you want the flag])
    # If you use Godot 3.0:
    # flag.position = [where you want the flag]
    add_child(flag)
```

Comment: Oh sweet. This is exactly what I needed. I got them spawning in the end just not quite as elegantly. Currently waiting for 3.0 to hit a more stable state since collision detection doesn't work for scenes loaded in with that method.

Thanks though. I'll bookmark this for Godot 3 :)

Comment: @crabcrabcam Im running 2.12 and having an area2d with Collisionshape2D lets me check collisions for both scenes.

Answer (score 0):

As you already noticed, when you call [`add_child()`](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_node.html#class-node-add-child), there isn't a way to input the position at the same time.

To change the position, you modify the position variable on the instanced node.

```
scene_instance.position = Vector2(x, y)
```

The structure that this gives instancing/placing code looks something like this.

```
scene_instance = scene_being_instanced.instance()

# All modification you want to happen *before* the node(s) are added
scene_instance.position = Vector2(x, y)

self.add_child(scene_instance)

# All modifications you want to happen *after* the node(s) have been added
```

For more information, I recommend taking a look at the [Node documentation](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_node.html).